# Remove the last punctuation in list of numbers in Python

Tags: pandas, list

I have variable of numbers and letters and want a code to remove the apostrophe between each number/letter and only keeping the first and last apostrophe for the variable. Desired output is shown below

```
numbers = 'V7780T103', '494368103', '003654100', '26210C104' 

output should be

numbers = 'V7780T103, 494368103, 003654100, 26210C104'
```

Comment: `','.join(numbers)`

Comment: thanks thats worked a treat!

Comment: No problem @Zack. :)